# MYSQL find matching ids from another column

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select matching data from another column given this example:

```
id    user_id     match_id
1     3           4
2     3           5
3     4           3
4     4           6
```

Note: ID column is an auto_increment column

So basically the output should be that user_id 3 and user_id 4 are matched since user_id 3 has user_id 4 in the match_id column while user_id 4 has user_id 3 in the match_id column

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table you listed is `user_matching`, and the table you're trying to join on is `users` and it has both an `id` and `username` column, you can use the following (Use `u.` and `u2.` to differentiate between fields on the matched user/member, or the original user/member):

```
SELECT u.username, u2.username AS match_username
FROM user_matching m
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN users u2 on u2.id = u.match_id
```